# Barplot is not showing x-axis title and y-axis numbers

Tags: r, plot

I have created a `term-document` matrix and want to use this to create a `barplot`.
I thought there would be categorical names on the x-axis with title "Word frequencies".
On y-axis should be number scaling from 0-60, but there is only a scale with no units.

[Barplot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3JaT.png)

I have just started learning R and I follow the instructions on http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/word-cloud-generator-in-r-one-killer-function-to-do-everything-you-need
to learn to create boxplot of frequencies.
But it turns out different since I use a different data set.

I am stuck on this for long and would really appreciate some help,thanks!

## Build a term-document matrix

```
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
head(d, 15)
```

## Bar plot of the frequency for the top 13

```
barplot(d[1:13,]$freq, las = 2, 
names.arg = d[1:13,]$word,
col ="lightgreen", main ="Most frequent words",
ylab = "Word frequencies")
```

Comment: I used data("crude") instead of docs in your code, and the rest of your code made the appropriate barplot with axes labelled and everything (like your example); what does head(d,15) show? Or str(d)? Can you edit your question with this information?